# Unix script removes content of last line of XML file

Tags: shell, unix

In our main script the replace() function is called like below.

Here after replacing mail string in "sed command" the file is moved "mv $tmpfile $file;" both are successful and echos in output console "- file $file has been successfully edited!"

everything looks fine. But,

Problem is in the replaced xml file the last line is removed. for example if the last line of xml file is  tag, this line is removed.

Someone help me why the last line of xml file is removed?

#replace wrapper function

f_replace(){

file=$1

#-i    Ignores upper/lower case distinction during  comparisons.

COUNT=$(egrep -i $SEARCH_STRING $file | wc -l)

if [ $COUNT -ne 0 ]; then

#found - add it to list

echo "$COUNT time(s)     $file" | tee -a $FILE_LIST

#tmpfile erstellen

tmpfile="$file."`date +%Y%m%d`"_"`date +%H%M%S`;

>$tmpfile;

sed -e 's%[dD][eE][vV]@[dD][oO][mM][aA][iI][nN].[cC][oO][mM]%test@domain.com%g' $file >>$tmpfile;

rc=$?;

[ "$rc" != "0" ] && echo "ERROR: couldn't edit file $file and write it into $tmpfile!" | tee -a $FILE_LIST && return;

mv $tmpfile $file;

rc=$?;

[ "$rc" != "0" ] && echo "ERROR: couldn't move tmp file $tmpfile to $file!" | tee -a $FILE_LIST && return;

echo "- file $file has been successfully edited!" | tee -a $FILE_LIST

fi

}

Comment: is it possible to have the exact XML file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use one the following replacement command using either `sed` or `awk`:

```
sed 's/dev@domain.com/test@domain.com/gI' $file >>$tmpfile
```

Example:

```
$ echo dEv@domain.com Dev@domain.com | sed 's/dev@domain.com/test@domain.com/gI'                                                               
test@domain.com test@domain.com
```

or

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1}/dev@domain.com/{gsub(/dev@domain.com/,"test@domain.com")}1'
```

Example:

```
$ echo dEv@domain.com dEv@domain.com | awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1}/dev@domain.com/{gsub(/dev@domain.com/,"test@domain.com")}1'                    
test@domain.com test@domain.com
```

**Also could you explain what does this line do** `>$tmpfile;` ?

Comment: Thanks Allan.

 

But (sed 's/dev@domain.com/test@domain.com/gI' $file >>$tmpfile) will not work in my case because [I is a non-standard GNU sed extension.] for insensitive notation.

 

Mine is Sun Solaris, not redhat like.

 

i will refer awk also later, thanks.

 

[>$tmpfile; it's not needed I will delete]

 

Solution:

 

By the way It is solved by appending a new line to $file before processing sed command. Means due to some reason(might be bug) sed deletes the content of last line of xml file, the new line added by me will be deleted.

 

problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

By the way It is solved by appending a new line to $file before processing sed command. Means due to some reason(might be bug) sed deletes the content of last line of xml file, the new line added by me will be deleted.

problem solved.